# Drawing a wind turbine generator with css & html or canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas, responsive-design

I am looking for an advice. I have to draw a wind turbine generator. I'm guessing its possible with html, css or canvas but maybe it would take ages.

I have in mind to do it with just images, have the main image for the generator and then have other images over the main one. I think it's the easiest solution to achieve it.

It has to have responsive as well.

[image]

The small pieces change the color depending on the data. So I am thinking to replace the images depending on it.

Any recommendation?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A nice way would be to use SVG so you can dynamically change color of the pieces

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I´ve never used it. Could you tell me a tutorial to build it?. Thanks Baptiste

Comment: I agree that SVG would be the best choice, but if SVG is new to you choose css or canvas - whichever you know better.

Comment: Well, both SVG and canvas isn't easy to start. Do you already have all the images separated ? If you have the main image as background you could try to draw svg on top of it thanks to Illustrator or Gravit Designer (free)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking to use Photoshop and have the main image as background and draw a piece in different layers. Then export it as SVG. I wonder if it would work.... I´ve never done it before. Do ye recommend me Gravit Designer?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could skin this cat in several ways, but if you're sure that these are all the components you need (and you won't need to keep expanding it), I agree that canvas is overkill.

Probably all you need is some markup like this:

```
<div id="turbine">
    <div id="injector"></div>
    <div id="motor"></div>
    <div id="block"></div>
    <div id="battery"></div>
</div>
```

And some CSS that looks something like this:

```
#turbine {
    background: url("turbine-main.png");
    position: relative;
}
#injector {
    background: url("injector-green.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 130px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
}
#injector.failing {
    background: url("injector-red.png");
}
#motor {
    background: url("motor-green.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 140px;
}
#motor.failing {
    background: url("motor-red.png");
}
```

Rinse and repeat for each part (adjusting image names, coordinates, and size as necessary, so that your pieces fit nicely over the main image). Add and remove the `failing` class from your individual pieces to toggle the red/green for each part, probably using javascript. (Or just do it in the HTML, if this is a statically rendered page.)

If you should be able to click these engine parts and jump to additional information, replace my `<div>`'s with `<a>`'s.